# htaccess URL rewrite page.php?page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a solution for this. Need to rewrite two URLs:

```
/page.php?page=onama
/page.php?page=pravila
```

**to**

```
/onama    
/pravila
```

I tried many different solutions, and none of them are working. However, I did rewrite these URLs like I said, but then my page isn't opening so I guess it's all in the details.

For the hint:

- page.php file is in root directory - it's full of if-else statements which includes other .php files from /pages/ directory into page.php file
- onama.php and pravila.php files are in /pages/ directory

**EDIT:**

I guess I'm lucky :)
Tried one more time with this and it worked, I'm not expert in .htaccess rules but this is the solution for mine problem:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&\s]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1&r [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT (new problem)**

I'm trying to make two rewrite rules and can't get them to working together.
So, the problem is with RULE 1 and RULE 2.

When RULE 1 is first in `.htaccess` file, it's working like a charm, but then I have a problem with RULE 2 - gives me a blank page.

When RULE 2 is first in `.htaccess` file, RULE 1 doesn't work - gives me 404 page.

In both cases, URL are SEF and working as it should, but the content isn't displayed.

**My htaccess file:**

```
# RULE 1 - rewriting "/index.php?view=X" to "/X" 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1&r [L,QSA]

# END OF RULE 1

# RULE 2 - rewriting "page.php?page=X" to "/X"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1&r [L,QSA]

# END OF RULE 2

#RULE 3 - rewriting "index.php" to "/"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#END OF RULE 3
```

Comment: Yeah, details are important here I suppose. Unfortunately we have virtually none...

Comment: You say you need to rewrite `/page.php?page=X` to `/X`  this means that whenever a user navigates to `/page.php?page=X` the code in `/X` is ran instead, maybe you need to to the opposite? Maybe you need a redirect? I'm not sure, however the rest of the question implies that there's nothing really in `/X` and it's just an intended shorthand for something else.

Comment: This reads like standard rewriting rules. You say "I tried many different solutions, and none of them are working", so we wonder: what have you tried and why did it not work for you although it works for others? There is little sense in us giving you the 659365923654956th example for such rules if it is unclear why rewriting does not work for you. So please: add your attempted rules and explain what you actually mean by "does not work". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post, I hope it has enough details now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pravila$  "/page.php?page=pravila"
RewriteRule ^onama$    "/page.php?page=onama"
```

Your Apache needs to be configured to Allow Override in this directory for .htaccess to work.

Comment: This isn't working. Normally I did this before with these rules and it worked, but not with this script.